# How to store multiple features for face and find distance?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, face-recognition

I am working on a project based on the facial recognition and verification. I am using Siamese network to get the 128 vector of the face ( Embeddings ).

I am storing the encodings/embeddings of the person's face in the database and then checking or say matching the incoming face's encodings with the previously stored encodings to recognize the person.

To make a robust system, I have to store more than one encodings of the same person. When I have used only a single encoding vector, and matched with :

From `face_recognition` library (to get distance):

```
face_recognition.compare_faces( stored_list_of_encodings, checking_image_encodings )
```

That doesn't work all the time because I have only compared with a single encoding. To make a system sufficient for most cases, I want to store minimum 3 encodings of a same person and then compare with the new data.

Now the question: How to store multiple embeddings of a same person and then compare the distance?

I am using `face_recognition` as the library and Siamese Network for feature extraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using an SVM classifier to classify the faces? So the input to the SVM classifier would be the vector of size 128. You can then compile a few of the vectors belonging to the face of a single person (3 in your case) and fit it to an SVM as a class. You can then do the same for different faces (classes).

Then, when predicting a face, simply feed in the new vector and run

```py
svm.predict([..])
```

I had a similar use-case for my project, but I was using Facenet instead as the feature extractor. Works perfectly.

Comment: Can you share a tutorial like regarding how to do that ... I mean the Steps? Because I don't know about SVM. Any help would be appreciated !!

Comment: Please have a look at this well detailed guide for reference: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-face-recognition-system-using-facenet-in-keras-and-an-svm-classifier/

Answer (score 1):

Theres multiple approaches to this, i have worked on Face recognition quite extensively and there are a few things that i tried. You can do some of the following.

**Create a KNN classifier**

The way to do this is to create a db of sorts, where each feature has a person name associated with it (in this case a feature is representative of one face image of a person). Then at comparison time, you compute the distance of your query feature with each representation. You take the comparisons with the N smallest distances. You can then go through the N distances and see what classes each belong to, and you can then use the maximum occurring label, and this will be your target class. In my experience though this isn't extremely robust (though this is entirely dependent on the type of your test data, mine had to do with alot of in the wild images, so this wasnt robust enough)

**Averaged Representations**

Another approach that i used was that i averaged the representations for each person. If i had 5 images, i would take the mean or the median of the 5 representations extracted from those representations. In my experience median worked better than mean. You will now have an average representation affiliated with each person, you can just take the distance with each average representation, and the one with the least distance will be your target class.

**Cluster Representations**

Another approach is to cluster representation into clusters using DBScan, and then at runtime classify the query rep into a cluster and take the majority class in that cluster as the label

In my experience average representation is the best, but you do end up needing multiple images, at-least 5 i think. But in my case i needed at-least 5 since i was catering to multiple angles and what not.

**NOTE ::** SVM is a BAD approach, you limit your DB size, and every-time you need to add a new person to the DB you would need to train a new SVM for the extra class that has just popped up

Also, for a storing purposes you could always store it in a JSON

Comment: If you vectorize your distance/similarity algorithms they too are very fast. Moreover if  you use something like cupy that does these distance/similarity on the gpu, Then that too is very fast, and the good part about this is that you use thresholding, so depending on your problem you can have a very secure (high threshold) or loose (low threshold) system

Comment: And my bad, my opinion regarding SVM was flawed

Comment: SVM is not a database of known faces. Therefore you would need to create a label-class for each face in your dataset. What you do instead is creating an algorithim that can tell if two inputs of faces are from the same person. So you can compare the unknown face to every face in your DB. Because classification with a svm is relativley fast i guess this will work in an acceptable time even if you have a million faces to test against. Also you could prefilter your dataset based on gender, ethnicity etc.. to become faster. But +1 because what you tell is true regarding the accepted answer.

Comment: Its not about the speed, knn probably will be faster than the svm solution. I just have a feeling that the comparisation between two faces is way more robust to differences in the angle of the picture or other external influences. So if all your pictures are shot from the same angle and same quality knn is for sure the way to go. But if you are not sure where your pictures are coming from and what angle/quality/light-conditions you'll have, then comparing should be way more robust than recognizing.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with what you are saying when SVM limits the DB size? SVM has many advantages a couple of which is that 1) it is a more robust algorithm than KNN 2) During inference time, you do not have to load in training data from the database. Imagine a scenario where your database is always increasing to recognize 200 faces, the inference time would then be proportional to the I/O speed of db, whereas SVM, you are simply storing the boundaries (and its fast).3) Yes you do have to retrain the SVM, but fitting an SVM is fast. But once you have fitted it, then using it is no sweat

Comment: what you and what @FlorianH are talking about are two different things, you say that we should train a multiclass SVM which classifies embeddings into a class, the problem with this is that every-time a new person is added to your "DB" a new class is also added, this means you would now have to retrain the svm with the data for this extra class. Florian suggests that we use a SVM to say whether two embeddings belong to the same person or not. So a binary classification problem, yes or no.

Comment: Also in my personal experience even the binary classification doesn't work very well.  This is due to the lack of real life like data (atleast in my case). To train a robust enough binary SVM we need large amounts of data, and need to make pairs in such a way that similar faces are paired together and a SVM trained accordingly. The problem that occurs is that when you use open source datasets to make such pairs, you train a biased classifier, since open source datasets like MS-Celeb are different then real life face data (good lighting, good angles, hogh quality images)

Comment: I had angled images in my case, with 30-40% occlusion in many cases, as well as bad lighting, and the images were not of very high quality. (larger images = longer face detection times). I tried making pairs for my DB, but obviously the dataset was unbalanced, and even then the SVM would fail for newer faces / different kind of faces

Answer (score 0):

You can store all the face embeddings in a database/datastructure which supports nearest neighbors queries and then for any given face you ought to find a match, get it's nearest neighbors embeddings in the database. With k nearest neighbors and their distances to query item, you can decide which person this new face belongs to (if it belongs to known persons at all).

You can take a look at [Approximate Nearest Neighbor Benchmark](http://ann-benchmarks.com/annoy.html) for available options.

Just remember, they are called approximate so you won't get exact results but it is the best option you have if you are dealing with a large amount of entities. If it's not the case with you, you can just use brute force nearest neighbors solutions already provided in sklearn to get exact matches.